# UI Guidelines for Android Honeycomb on Tablets

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, ui-guidelines

The UI in Android Honeycomb is very different. I'm looking for things that have changed that would be of interest to developers. Google hasn't updated it's UI guidelines yet, so I am trying to find this stuff out by inspecting the layouts. I am mainly interested in dimensions of icons and new types of views.

The action bar height is 56dp (`?android:attr/actionBarSize`). It seems that the menu icons are 32 x 32 dp now, they were 48 x 48 dp before. Since they are in the action bar, they have a lot of padding around them. The size of a menu icon with padding is 64 x 56 dp. I needed this since I was trying to put a `ProgressBar` as a menu item.

Anything else change? Also, I'm interested in the size of some common UI patterns, like the widths for a list/detail layout like the mail client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out the latest [Icon Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) as well as the section on [Metrics and Grids](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html).

Also, you can see details about the [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) and other things that are [new to the platform](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/new-4-0.html).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to get the Motorola Xoom and check it out. If you don't have the money to support this investment then use the emulator.  Be sure to post your answers up here for others.

Comment: I feel that suggesting people to buy device to learn the UI will be more or like making fun of them, if android future versions bring new UI what will the designers do, buy that one too.?     I think following the documentation and asking the experts and trying them in the emulator will be much more helping..

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand the quesiton 100%, but im pretty sure that the have put into the dev guide all the new stuff, such as new views and layout guidlines (such as fragments, and listfragments). Is there something else that im missing? Granted, the documentation for fragments is kinda weak.

Comment: I'm looking for the Honeycomb version of the [UI Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html). They haven't been updated for Honeycomb yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the new [guidelines for icon design](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#design-tips).

Haven't seen the new views graphically but at least the [fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) has been updated recently.